# How do I add a JS target to a KMM project?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I have an AndrodiStudio KMM project and I'd like to add a JS target.

Given that JS development is only available in IntelliJ, I'd expect that I have to open the project in IDEA add a "Module" -- but I don't even know which one to choose -- none of them seem to be a "right" fit:

- In the Gradle section, there is "Kotlin/JS for browser and "Kotlin/JVM". Adding "Kotlin/JS" breaks* the Gradle build for the whole project. "Kotlin/Multiplatform" doesn't sound like what I want since I already have the "shared" module for that (although it doesn't include JS)
- In the Kotlin section, there is "KS | IDEA". Obviously, I don't want to  add something based on the "IDEA build system" to a gradle.kts based project.

So my question is:

- Which module template is the best starting point for adding "jsApp" (or webApp) alongside "iosApp" and "androidApp" (in AndroidStudio or Idea?)?
- What do I need to add to "shared/build.gradle.kts" to support "jsMain" and "jsTest" folders? Is there a different / better starting point (e.g. tutorial or minimal "helloWorld" sample on Github covering *all* platforms)?

The current structure of my code corresponds 1:1 to the KMM project template in Android Studio: https://github.com/stefanhaustein/komponents

*) The error message:

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform', version: '1.4.31']
> Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version
```

Comment: Would also be interested to know why this Q is being downvoted? Am I overlooking something simple? Is this the wrong substack?

Comment: Hello! Basically, you need just to add `js()` target at your `shared/build.gradle.kts`. See [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-set-up-targets.html) doc page. After that, add your code to the `/src/jsMain/kotlin`. I agree that the documentation might be unclear on adding new targets, worth creating an issue at the Kotlin's issue tracker: kotl.in/issue

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by manually copying bits of the kotlin/js template... (your link doesn't describe what needs to go into `js()`. I have filed an issue as suggested here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45612 and here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-sample/issues/55 -- will add an answer with what I needed to do later here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working by creating a new Kotlin/JS project and copying it over to `jsApp` in the KMM project (parallel to `iosApp` etc.) The minimum `jsApp/build.gradle.kts` seems to be:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("js")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":shared"))
}

kotlin {
    js() {
        browser {
        }
    }
}
```

In `shared/build.gradle.kts`, I needed to add the following snippet to the kotlin section (parallel to `android()` and `ios{...}`

```
    js {
        browser {     
        }
    }
```

Pitfalls why this took me longer than one would expect:

- Bad time with forgetting `.kts` in `build.gradle.kts` and fantastic error messages
- Because the jsApp `build.gradle.kts` is now nested, the kotlin plugin can't have a `version` there apparently (guess it makes sense for consistency).
- The js source file name in `index.html` needs to match the module name (`jsApp` in my case).
- Don't forget `include(":jsApp")`in `settings.gradle.kts`

Recommended steps:

- Try to first get the "web" module working
- Use a gradle based run configuration
- Only when the web sample project works in the new structure, wire up the shared code

Comment: did you succeed to compile framework for js from android studio? i see this error  What went wrong:
Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin'.
> Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists.
in 
    js {
        browser {     
        }
    }

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I think it worked. Haven't done much kmm for a while but hope to be back to it soon...

Comment: Actually now I am running into the same issue

Comment: Wondering if it's related to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33191 ... Did you find any workaround @VadimEksler

Comment: The "trick" is to delete the clean task from the KMM template from the root build.gradle.kts.

Comment: those task was an issue